# Local storage "REMOVE" button is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, e-commerce

I am having trouble with removing an item from shopping cart after adding it.The error is:**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**
Here goes my Script:

```
const addEspresso = () =>{
  var Espresso, esp, eObj;
Espresso = {
  name : "Espresso",
  type : "strong",
  imgSrc : "images/c7.png"
};

localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(Espresso));


esp = localStorage.getItem("Espresso");
eObj = JSON.parse(esp);



let espresso = "";
espresso += `
         <div class="productDiv">
         <p>${eObj.name}</p> 
         <p>${eObj.type}</p>
         <img src="${eObj.imgSrc}">
         <button onclick="removeCI()"id = "remove">REMOVE</button>
         </div>
         `
         

          

document.getElementById("productList").innerHTML = espresso
}

const remove = document.getElementById("remove");

const removeI = (e) =>{
  var clicked = e.target;
  clicked.parentElement.remove();
}
const removeCI = () =>{
  remove.addEventListener("click", removeI)
}
```

Now html

```
<div id = productList>

</div>

<div class="coffeeT">
      <button id="espAdd"onclick="addEspresso()">Add</button>
    </div>
```

**Also it would be very nice if someone could explain how to add a product to local storage more than 1 time!
Anticipate thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting up a button with an id (to remove) but when you add more than one espresso, you have multiple buttons with the same id. That will cause problems. Instead, use a classname:

```
   <button class="btn-remove">REMOVE</button>
```

We need to keep track of these items with something, how about an index. The data-index attribute will help us when it's time to delete

```
eObj.forEach((item,i) => {  // item is the item, i is the index
      espresso += `
             <div class="productDiv" data-index="${i}">
```

Then create a single event listener that will know when the remove button was clicked, and act accordingly:

```
 document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-remove')) {
    // before removing, lets get the data-index value so we can remove the right one from localStorage
    let index = e.target.closest('.productDiv').dataset.index
    e.target.closest('.productDiv').remove();
    // adjust localStorage
    let eObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Espresso"));
    eObj.splice(index,1)
    localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(eObj));
  }
 })
```

Complete code:

```
const addEspresso = () => {
  let Espresso, esp, eObj;
  Espresso = {
    name: "Espresso",
    type: "strong",
    imgSrc: "images/c7.png"
  };

  // get the existing localStorage first
  esp = localStorage.getItem("Espresso");
  if (!esp) eObj = [];
  else eObj = JSON.parse(esp);
  // it should be an array or create one if empty
  eObj.push(Espresso)
  // add eObj to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(eObj));

  let espresso = "";
  eObj.forEach((item,i) => {  // item is the item, i is the index
  espresso += `
         <div class="productDiv" data-index="${i}">
         <p>${eObj.name}</p> 
         <p>${eObj.type}</p>
         <img src="${eObj.imgSrc}">
         <button class="btn-remove">REMOVE</button>
         </div>
        `
   });
  document.getElementById("productList").innerHTML = espresso
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-remove')) {
    // before removing, lets get the data-index value so we can remove the right one from localStorage
    let index = e.target.closest('.productDiv').dataset.index
    e.target.closest('.productDiv').remove();
    // adjust localStorage
    let eObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Espresso"));
    eObj.splice(index,1)
    localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(eObj));
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!That worked!But let's say I have 1 more object property called "quantity"with value 0,how do I make the value increase and for the div to not appear again?Same thing with local storage,I need the product to be added there more than 1 time.Do I add the value to each of them or how?

Comment: not sure what you mean by quantity, but I adjusted the rest, look at the answer, alot of it updated.

Comment: Thank you,everything works good, but I get a small error:GET file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JSLearn/myC3/myC3/undefined net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Image (async)
addEspresso @ shopJS.js:37
onclick @ coffeeShop.html:54

Answer (score 0):

```
const remove = document.getElementById("remove");
if (remove) {
    const removeI = (e) => {
        var clicked = e.target;
        clicked.parentElement.remove();
    }
    if (removeI ) {
        const removeCI = () => {
            remove.addEventListener("click", removeI, false)
        }
    }
}
```

Please check this

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: removeCI is not defined.Maybe I should make this whole a function?